# How to push git changes to both beta site and live site?

Tags: git

This is our setup:

- Each developer has his own website to develop on and do git stuff on.
- Each developer creates a new branch (based on the master branch) for each issue he works on.
- We have a beta site that is kept up to date with the "beta" branch.
- We have a live site that is kept up to date with the "master" branch.
- When a developer is done with an issue, he merges it into the beta branch.
- When we are done testing on the beta site, we merge that issue's branch into the master branch.

Somehow this doesn't work perfectly all the time.

Sometimes there is a merge conflict when trying to merge an issue branch into the beta branch.  Resolving this conflict somehow merges the entire beta branch into the issue's branch, which means that when that issue gets merged into master, EVERYTHING from beta will go live.

Any ideas on the best way we should use git in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you handle bug fixes while beta testing? How far have `beta` and `master` drifted apart? Check with `git diff`.

Comment: "Resolving this conflict somehow merges the entire beta branch into the issue's branch". No, it doesn't. Only if you chose to resolve your conflicts that way. And as you see, that is often a suboptimal choice.

Answer (score 1):

seems like your merge-conflict procedure is a bit wrong
It sounds like to solve the conflicts people do merge the beta into the issue branch
whenever there is a conflict you can do one of the following:

1. If you can push directly to beta
   a. git checkout beta

   b. get merge issue

   c. resolve conflicts

   d. git push
2. If you can't push directly to beta

   a. git checkout -b  issue

   b. git merge beta

   c. resolve conflicts

   d. git push

   e. merge through PR on the server

Answer (score 1):

With that plan, beta and master have likely drifted apart; you can check with `git diff beta master`. The core problems are you're making issue branches from one branch and merging them into a different branch. And you're QAing the whole beta branch, but you're releasing issue-by-issue.

You're making issue branches from one branch and merging them into a different branch. That's a recipe for conflicts. Beta is supposed to be a superset of master. But you're merging your fixed issue branches into master, the bug fixes never get back into beta. Beta will increasingly become filled with buggy versions of what's in master. Beta and master will drift further and further apart, you will get more and more conflicts, and beta testing will drift further and further from reality.

For QA to be meaningful you have to be testing what you're releasing. If beta has to be master + the issue branch. It likely is not. You need to either QA and release the whole beta branch, or QA and release issue by issue.

If you want the whole branch approach, try [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). It ensures all the pieces stay in sync.

With only one test server you can only test one issue at a time making a beta branch pointless. Get rid of the beta branch and test directly from the issue branch. This is the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow). And rather than having *one* dedicated QA server, consider using a service that lets you spin up servers on demand so you can QA many issues in parallel. I've had good success with [Heroku Pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines).